jwt token cookie is not persist in production environment react/nest js
I work in a vite react / nest js website and I have implemented user login using passport jwt and cookies as follows
my login backend is
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @Post("/login")
  async login(
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto,
    @Res({passthrough: true}) response: Response
    // @Res() response: Response
  ) {
    const { username, password } = createUserDto;
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    const jwt = await this.authService.login(user);
    
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_APP_DEVELOPMENT !== "true";
    response.cookie("Authentication", jwt, {
      httpOnly: isProduction,
      secure: isProduction,
      // sameSite: 'none',
      // path: '/',
      // maxAge: 3600000,
    });
    return user;

and my auth service is
  async validateUser(
    username: string,
    password: string,
  ): Promise<AuthenticatedUser> {
    let user: AuthenticatedUser = await this.usersService.getUser(username);
    let role = 'user';
    if (!user) {
      user = await this.adminService.getOne({ username: username });
      role = 'admin';
    }

    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      return { ...user, role };
    }

    return null;
  }

  async login(user: AuthenticatedUser) {
    user = user['_doc'];
    const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user._id, role: user.role };
    return this.jwtService.sign(payload)
  }

my main.ts cors configuration is
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: originsDomains,
    credentials: true, 
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    Headers: true,
    exposedHeaders: 'Set-Cookie',
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: [
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'Content-Type',
      'Authorization'
    ]
  };
  app.enableCors(corsOptions);

when I login the cookie is returned in the browser and working good in localhost but in production environment (tried render and vercel) and it immediately disappears, how to persist the cookie in production environment
